# c# Detect if specific window (IE Browser, file explorer etc) closes/user presses X button?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently doing a WPF app where you will be able to open apps suchs as IE and file explorer (more to come), and when you start it, a button is created and put in a custom appbar/taskbar.

So to the problem, we are using Process.Start() to start the apps, so we are currently checking this

```
this.ProgramProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.ProgramProcess.Exited += (sender, e) => { RemoveRunningProgram((Process)sender); };
```

and the RemoveRunningProgram method looks like this

```
private void RemoveRunningProgram(Process process)
        {
          App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate { TaskbarWindow.RunningPrograms.Remove(this); });
        }
```

So the main thought is, if you close a window by the user pressing the X button in the top right corner to close the window, the appbar button/icon will disappear.

So couple of the problems;
If you open 1 IE browser, it works fine, but if you open more than one, you will have to close all windows, for all the icons to disappear.

It takes a LONG time for the computer to see if the file explorer is closed or not, sometimes not even notice it.

Am I thinking at the right spot where I should make adjustments?

RunningProgram.cs:

```
public class RunningProgram : Button
    {
        private IntPtr ProgramHandle { get; set; }
        private string ProgramName { get; set; }
        public Process ProgramProcess { get; set; }

        public List<Process> procList = new List<Process>();


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

       
        public RunningProgram(IntPtr programHandle, string programName, Thickness margin, string imagePath, Process programProcess)
        {

            this.ProgramHandle = programHandle;
            this.ProgramName = programName;
            this.Margin = margin;
            this.Background = SetButtonBackground(imagePath);
            this.Width = 70;
            this.Height = 70;
            this.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ShowWindow_Click);
            this.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
            this.ProgramProcess = programProcess;
            this.procList.Add(ProgramProcess);
            this.ProgramProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            this.ProgramProcess.Exited += (sender, e) => { RemoveRunningProgram((Process)sender); }; 
            
              
        }

        private void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            RemoveRunningProgram((Process)sender);
        }

        private void RemoveRunningProgram(Process process)
        {
              App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate { TaskbarWindow.RunningPrograms.Remove(this); });
        }

private void ShowWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
                ShowWindow(ProgramHandle, 3);
                SetForegroundWindow(ProgramHandle);
                GetForegroundWindow();
            
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use a background task to just watch the process id's that are on your list are still active?  You could run it every 10 seconds and just check whether the process id's on your list are still there in the list of processes?

Comment: @KevinCook Since, especially IE, changes its pID and the ID we kept track of isnt the initial ID anymore of that window. So if we list all the processes ID that id wont be there anymore

Comment: It was in addition to your normal check mainly for the slow file explorer issues to try to detect that removal faster.